# YouTube Data API: How many video does standard feed return?

Tags: youtube-api

I am calling YouTube Data API to get the standard feed videos like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/standardfeeds/HK/most_popular_Music?time=this_week
```

Then I'm paging through to get more. But it usually ends at around 100 videos. Is that normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `<openSearch:totalResults>90</openSearch:totalResults>` element in the feed indicates that there are (approximately) 90 videos in that feed.